# Error: Can't find python in singularity container

Tags: python

I am new to the use of the containers.

I am using a singularity container (I didn't create it, the technical support provide it to me) and I get this error when I use python -- version:

```
Singularity> python --version
bash: python: command not found
```

When I use which python nothing appears.

When I use type -a python:

```
Singularity> type -a python
bash: type: python: not found
```

When I use ls -l :

```
Singularity> ls -l /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3628976 Sep 30 09:38 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Sep 30 09:38 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 Apr 11  2018 /usr/bin/python3-futurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     388 Apr 11  2018 /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     364 Aug 22  2016 /usr/bin/python3-qr
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Oct  8 08:12 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Oct  8 08:12 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Oct  8 08:12 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Oct  8 08:12 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
```

I am using this container on a super computer.
I also tried to set pythonpath but it didn't worked, it still can't find python. I also tried to set $PATH, but it didn't work.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
Do you have any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: What does "run a configure" mean exactly? what is the complete error message? what is the software you are trying to install? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: Thank you. I edited it including the error I get.

Comment: There is no command `python` in your `ls` output, so a `not found` error seems like expected behavior. Try `python2.7`, which is present, for Python2. Try `python3` or `python3.6` for your installed Python3. It's all there in your `ls` output.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can set the command `python` such that it refers to python 2.7? I am trying to install a software and it cannot find python when I use `./configure --enable-2d-adaptivity`

Comment: This is the error I get: `configure: Checking for Python automagic.
configure: No Python automagic.
checking for python... no
configure: error: Cannot find python in your system path
`